# Reload all fragments at once present in a ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-filter

I Have a ViewPager in my activity which contains 5 fragments,I
 fixed a menu on toolbar which used as filter, on click on menu
 item I need to change views on all fragments,

I used to clear all the fragments in ViewPager and attached new instances of fragments,this displays correct views but while creating new
 views I used to show a progress bar on screen but It's not showing as
 we set, it calls after the change of all views.

The thing I doubt was is this correct method to change all views by replacing fragments with new instances Or there is any other method to change data in fragments respective to my context

Thank you

**Edit:**

clearing adapter for create new views

```
viewPagerAdapter.fragmentArrayList.clear();
viewPagerAdapter.fragmentTitle.clear();
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: can you put code for more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh all your fragment at once you can `setAdapter` of `ViewPager` again than it will refresh your all fragments like this;

```
    mViewPager.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
    //If you want set current postion for adapter
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(theCurrentPage);
```

Comment: yeah! its already working but there is some stuck while doing this

Comment: I used to show a progress bar on screen while creating view but it stuck

Comment: Show your progress bar just before setting your adapter again

Comment: Yes I did the same but it's not working, it shows only after setting views .. this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are rightfully doubting whether destroying and recreating all your fragments is a good method if you only want to filter the list of fragments that your `ViewPager` is showing. It amounts to unnecessarily wasting considerable resources.

Instead you either manipulate your fragment list (and fragment title list?) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or implement a [Filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470863/filter-android-listview-with-predefined-filters/39472177#39472177).

So you go:

```
viewPagerAdapter.fragmentArrayList.remove(index);
```

or

```
viewPagerAdapter.fragmentArrayList.remove(fragment);
```

and then you say:

```
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Concerning the progress bar, where in your XML layout is it located? Within the view pager? Then move it outside. Somewhere else? Then show us your XML and the code creating and showing it.

Comment: Yeah ! i did the same work, I need to clear all the fragments so I used clear(). and It is Progress Dialog not progress bar (in activity)

Comment: Are you saying that opposite to what the title of your question is suggesting your problem is not whether and how to reload all fragments at once, but how to show the progress dialog? Then give us more code!